# jquery slider working inside a css flyout menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zen-cart

I'm using a zencart with a css flyout header menu and I also want use the jquery slider widget as one of the options in this menu but when I put it in there the little sliders don't appear correctly, it's like they've collapsed.

I've put together a fiddle which although it has all the code doesn't seem to be working, it's hopefully something stupid I'm not doing coz all the code is there as far as I can see.

can anyone help me out please
http://jsfiddle.net/4VU8D/

EDIT: here's a slightly better but still not working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4VU8D/1)

Comment: Try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4VU8D/1/

Comment: thanks, I forgot to set the library on the left, d'oh. Other than that you just cleaned it up right? I can't find any logical changes and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out, can anyone help me?

Comment: I managed to get the fiddle working properly, I didn't realise you had to copy and paste the custom jquery code if you'd already set the jquery on the panel on the left. Anyway, you can see the issue now - http://jsfiddle.net/AUJPh/ the sliders aren't showing up. I thought it might be to do with z-index because some of the css menu's elements have z-index attached, but changing the sliders to a high number didn't help

Comment: That's cause than you need to select from the frameworks panel **jQuery (edge)** and check on **jQuery UI** http://jsfiddle.net/AUJPh/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've only included the jQuery Framework, but not the jQuery UI.